# Column names out of values using Tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(event=c("A", "B", "C"), value=c(200,300,400))
df
  event value
1     A   200
2     B   300
3     C   400
```

and want to get

```
  event A_value B_value C_value
1     A     200      NA      NA
2     B      NA     300      NA
3     C      NA      NA     400
```

Do you have a solution?

Thank you very much.

(I tried tidyr::spread but don't know how to keep "event" and also did not manage the right naming of the new columns. I need keeping "event", because I need to pipe the output further and use "event" again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround: create an additional column with the correct column names and then use that to spread the data:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
mutate(df, key = paste(event, "value", sep = "_")) %>% 
  spread(key, value)

#  event A_value B_value C_value
#1     A     200      NA      NA
#2     B      NA     300      NA
#3     C      NA      NA     400
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: how would you now remove the "event" column and collapse the NA-values? Do you understand what I mean? I tried using aggregate and it works, but I looks ugly to me. Is there a more elegant solution? Thank you

Comment: I dont understand what u mean

Comment: In the initial example: remove the column "event". Now there is only one single value in every column. Say this is true for all my cases. Thus I want to only keep this value and "collapse" to a single row. Aggregate cannot "pick" the only notnan value, can it? (For aggregate one needs to add a common column, I guess) Thx

Comment: You have to update your question with the expected output. Also note that this would normally be better as a separate question

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I post a seperate question.